# How to save the post processing scripts configuration with Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I have made a temperature ⨉ fan speed tower which needed 3x9-1 ChangeAtZ post processing scripts and it took me quite much time to configure them all (and check it twice). Is there a way to save this, so that I wouldn't need to make them all again if something went wrong and I needed to start over or if I wanted to do something similar again ?

Comment: Have you tried saving as 3mf file (don't know if this works for the script input), I use this to save materials and configuration options. When I reopen the file I delete the STL and load a new one, slice and print.

Comment: Yes, I have. It didn't work. Post processing scripts are not changed when I load a .3mf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to fred_dot_u, I found the solution : 
the post processing scripts configuration is saved... in the printer profile. So, you cannot directly duplicate it, but re-installing a second occurrence of the same printer will clear the post processing scripts list, you can get them back by selecting the modified one...

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Simplify3D user which allows one to save "factory" files. It appears that Cura supports [printer profile configuration and saving](https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/52032-manage-profiles).

From the above link, one is directed to enter the profile manager. You can duplicate an existing profile and rename it to separate it from the protected (standard/stock?) profiles.

Without using Cura to confirm this, I suspect that you'll discover this may be the solution you seek.

[image: profile manager]

Comment: I have tested this (printer profile level), this does not work, the plugins are not part of the profiles and the storage thereof. Maybe it is the printer profile?

Comment: Well, you were right... Except that this is worse than you thought : it appears that those script are saved **in** the printer profile X-(. Setting another instance of the same printer gave me on with the scripts and the other one without it... I'd like to select your answer, but since it is not on cura, it would need ot make a specific one :-/